# I can't run DataTable in VSCode

Tags: html, css

I'm having some errors using a table using DataTable in Visual Studio Code.

The errors have been commented out in the code for clarity on each line where they result.

I state that I have not installed any extensions in VSCode. Is this possibly necessary to use DataTable and Bootstrap?

On codepen or on JSFiddle the code works correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable();
});
```

```css
.dataTables_length,
.dataTables_wrapper {
    font-size: 1.6rem;

    select,
    input {
        background-color: #f9f9f9; /*semi-colon expected*/
        border: 1px solid #999; /*{ expected*/
        border-radius: 4px; /* { expected*/
        height: 3rem; /*{ expected*/
        line-height: 2; /*{ expected*/
        font-size: 1.8rem;/*{ expected*/
        color: #333;
    }

    .dataTables_length,
    .dataTables_filter {
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DataTables. You are trying to use sass in your CSS page and vscode doesn't recognize sass by default. To solve this

You can either install a sass compiler extension in vscode to compile your sass code to regular CSS or you can convert the sass code to regular CSS. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable();
});
```

```html
<!-- Add this to the head -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I deleted them! this is the example I was telling you. https://jsfiddle.net/08anv4e3/

Comment: I get this error: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: OOk, Only in VSCode is not working for me

Comment: @elfuso check this fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/uaqgxk31/